# vba runtime error 1004 application defined or object defined error

Tags: excel, runtime-error, vba

Something very strange happened. At one point this was working and all of a sudden now I get an error.

The issue is `fm` and `sm`, when the debug is on, `fm = Empty` and `sm = Empty`

Therefore `tval = Empty` the error occurs at line 34:

`tval = WorksheetFunction.Sum(ws.Range(ws.Cells(fm, 11), ws.Cells(sm, 11)))`

Full code:

```
Private Sub TextBox6_Change()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim sr, leg, lr, fm, sm, tval, sval, i, j As Long
    Dim wo, rc As String

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Cost Analysis") ' ws = Work Sheet
    sr = 5                                       ' sr = Start row
    lr = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row   ' lr = Last row
    wo = Trim(UserForm1.TextBox4.Value)          ' Work Order
    leg = Trim(UserForm1.TextBox5.Value)         ' leg
    rc = Trim(UserForm1.ComboBox3.Value)         ' rc = Root Cause

    If wo <> "" And leg <> "" And rc <> "" And TextBox6.Value <> "" Then

        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(ws.Cells(sr, 1).Resize(lr, 1), wo, _
                                                  ws.Cells(sr, 4).Resize(lr, 1), leg, _
                                                  ws.Cells(sr, 5).Resize(lr, 1), rc) > 0 Then

            For i = sr To lr

                If Trim(ws.Cells(i, 1)) = wo And Trim(ws.Cells(i, 4)) = leg Then

                    j = j + 1

                    If j = 1 Then
                        fm = i
                    End If

                    If Trim(ws.Cells(i, 5)) = rc Then
                        sm = i
                        Exit For
                    Else
                    End If

                End If
            Next

            tval = WorksheetFunction.Sum(ws.Range(ws.Cells(fm, 11), ws.Cells(sm, 11)))
            sval = WorksheetFunction.Sum(ws.Range(ws.Cells(fm, 11), ws.Cells(sm, 11))) * Trim(TextBox6.Value)

        Else
        End If
    End If

    UserForm1.TextBox7 = tval
    UserForm1.TextBox16 = sval

End Sub
```

Comment: you used `Application.WorksheetFunction` in previous lines, but changed it later for the `sum` function. You may consider an if statement as well so lr is not smaller than sr

Comment: In my case, lr can never be smaller than sr. Would you please write the if statement and let me know where to insert it?

Comment: Not the cause of your problem, but this line `Dim sr, leg, lr, fm, sm, tval, sval, i, j As Long` declares only j as Long, the others being Variants. Presumably a value is not being assigned to fm or sm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible that the inputs `wo` and `leg` are invalid? If so then

```
If Trim(ws.Cells(i, 1)) = wo And Trim(ws.Cells(i, 4)) = leg
```

will not evaluate to `True` for any `i`, and then `fm` and `sm` will be `Empty`. That would cause line 34 to throw an error.

Hope that helps.

Comment: You figured it out! everything entered into the wo needs to be in caps! How would I change that in the code?  wo = Trim(UserForm1.TextBox4.Value)

Comment: There is a `UCase` function to convert to upper case.

Comment: One other potential bug --- should your resizes be `Resize(lr-sr+1,1)`?

Comment: Where do you see that?

Comment: For instance, if sr = 5 and lr = 6, don't you want to resize to 2 rows (lr-sr+1) instead of lr rows?